# unable to build VSC devcontainer for Haskell on OS X Ventura

Tags: docker, macos, visual-studio-code, haskell

I'm trying to use the [official haskell devcontainer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/haskell) for vsc on OS X Ventura.

After moving the .devcontainer folder to the root of my project and clicking `Reopen in container`, this is what I get:

```
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.593Z] Dev Containers 0.266.1 in VS Code 1.74.2 (e8a3071ea4344d9d48ef8a4df2c097372b0c5161).
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.593Z] Start: Resolving Remote
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.610Z] Setting up container for folder or workspace: /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.613Z] Start: Check Docker is running
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.613Z] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.765Z] Stop (152 ms): Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.766Z] Server API version: 1.41
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.766Z] Stop (153 ms): Check Docker is running
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.766Z] Start: Run: docker volume ls -q
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.885Z] Stop (119 ms): Run: docker volume ls -q
[2022-12-27T12:44:59.898Z] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.021Z] Stop (123 ms): Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.022Z] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.150Z] Stop (128 ms): Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.150Z] Start: Run: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/samuelebonini/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --workspace-folder /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.311Z] (node:24087) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.311Z] (Use `Code Helper --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.312Z] @devcontainers/cli 0.25.2. Node.js v16.14.2. darwin 22.1.0 arm64.
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.312Z] Start: Run: docker buildx version
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.477Z] Stop (165 ms): Run: docker buildx version
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.477Z] github.com/docker/buildx v0.8.1 5fac64c2c49dae1320f2b51f1a899ca451935554
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.477Z] 
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.477Z] Start: Resolving Remote
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.479Z] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.490Z] Stop (11 ms): Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.491Z] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.604Z] Stop (113 ms): Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.606Z] Start: Run: docker inspect --type image debian:bullseye-slim
[2022-12-27T12:45:00.720Z] Stop (114 ms): Run: docker inspect --type image debian:bullseye-slim
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.021Z] local container features stored at: /Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/node_modules/vscode-dev-containers/container-features
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.022Z] Start: Run: tar --no-same-owner -x -f -
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.032Z] Stop (10 ms): Run: tar --no-same-owner -x -f -
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.033Z] Start: Run: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/devcontainercli/container-features/0.25.2-1672145102020/Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-1copy-35a5c23ba93fc94a4cdbfe5ffc09ab01 --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy/.devcontainer
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.415Z] [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                         
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.565Z] [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                         
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.665Z] [+] Building 0.0s (1/2)                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.24kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context:                                               0.0s
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.816Z] 
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.816Z] [+] Building 0.2s (2/3)                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.24kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim    0.1s
[2022-12-27T12:45:02.967Z] [+] Building 0.3s (2/3)                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.24kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim    0.3s
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.118Z] [+] Building 0.5s (2/3)                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.24kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim    0.4s
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.183Z] [+] Building 0.6s (3/3) FINISHED                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.0s
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.183Z]  => => transferring dockerfile: 2.24kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim    0.5s
error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to process "\"${templateOption:installZsh}\"": unsupported modifier (i) in substitution
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.200Z] Stop (1167 ms): Run: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/devcontainercli/container-features/0.25.2-1672145102020/Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-1copy-35a5c23ba93fc94a4cdbfe5ffc09ab01 --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy/.devcontainer
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.200Z] Error: Command failed: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/devcontainercli/container-features/0.25.2-1672145102020/Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-1copy-35a5c23ba93fc94a4cdbfe5ffc09ab01 --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy/.devcontainer
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.200Z]     at Doe (/Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1894:1669)
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.200Z]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.201Z]     at async EF (/Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1893:1978)
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.201Z]     at async uT (/Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1893:901)
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.201Z]     at async Poe (/Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1899:2128)
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.201Z]     at async Zf (/Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1899:3278)
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.201Z]     at async aue (/Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2020:15276)
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.201Z]     at async oue (/Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2020:15030)
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.202Z] Stop (3052 ms): Run: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/samuelebonini/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --workspace-folder /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.203Z] Exit code 1
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.205Z] Command failed: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/samuelebonini/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/samuelebonini/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --workspace-folder /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/samuelebonini/Desktop/APROG/second_mid_term/1copy/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-12-27T12:45:03.205Z] Exit code 1
```

I'm following the instructions on how to run a devcontainer in vsc, so I'm stuck and have no clue how to proceed. How do I fix this error?

Comment: I suspect this was caused by [microsoft/vscode-dev-containers#1659](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/pull/1659/files#diff-88c77ea7e130440c53ad113c3d9c456d8fad9fd7868bfe6df63bfe0b750c22eeL6-R8) - if you use a version from before that PR merged, does it work any better?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a Community Template which is no longer maintained. Also, have you copy pasted the source code? Instead can you use the `Dev Container: Add Dev Container Configuration Files` command to add the Haskell Template to your repo?

As the Haskell Template is no longer maintained, it will only receive security updates (if needed). List of all Templates is [here](https://containers.dev/templates)